# Split String Array using Regex - Java

Tags: java

I'm using Java and I have a String array. I want to split each item of array into smaller elements using Regex (similar to the split method of string but instead of applying split to string I want to apply it to a specific item in an array). How do I do this?

For example, suppose I have an array of sentences in an array called "sentences". Now I want to split this into a multi dimensional array where the first index would contain an index of sentence and the second index would contain an index of individual words. In other words, I want to split each sentences using a space.

To illustrate, suppose I have a String array with two values - as follows:

```
sentence[0] = "This is sentence one";
sentence[1] = "This is sentence two";
```

Now I want to  do two things here:

1. Create a multi dimensional array where index 1 contains sentence and where index two contains words
2. To do this I would need to split the sentence array. How would I do it to create multi dimensional array?

Comment: "apply it to a specific item" How is this items recognized?

Comment: Your edit doesn't make things clearer. Do you want to split each `String` of a `String[]` on a space?

Comment: I edited it further..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[][] a = new String[sentences.length][];

for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    String sentence = sentences[i];
    a[i] = sentence.split(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String[]> words = new ArrayList<>(sentences.length);
for(String item : sentences)
    words.add(item.split(" "));
```

Or if you really want to use Arrays only:

```
String[][] words = new String[sentences.length][];
for(int i=0;i<sentences.length;i++)
    words[i] = sentences[i].split(" ");
```